# The use of Camel and the JMS Component with IBM MQ

Tags: apache-camel, ibm-mq

Setting the context for my question regarding the use of Camel and the JMS Component:
•   The Camel Components currently supported for Message-Oriented-Middleware are ActiveMQ, AMQ and JMS.
•   The system that we are currently implementing Camel has external partner integration implementations for FTP, SFTP and IBM MQ.
•   We  had no problem implementing FTP and  SFTP Came  Routes.
•   This discussion may evolve into the use of IBM MQ specifically rather than a Camel implementation of IBM MQ and the JMS Component – hopefully not.

Our IBM MQ solution is problematic because the system we are integrating Camel into  has  IBM MQ sender and receiver implementations that were developed without the use of JMS (i.e., using the proprietary IBM Java  implementation of IBM MQ).
My guess is that if we try to utilize the JMS Camel Component with these legacy  IBM MQ end points it  will not work, then again maybe it will.
So, before we try  to create prototypes to try to test this  wired configuration, has anyone out there encountered this issue before and if so what was the final resolution?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Applications using MQ Java API operate well with applications using JMS.
When you define the queue (or topic) destination add the `targetClient` parameter and set it to 1 as documented [here (Apache Camel)](https://camel.apache.org/components/4.0.x/jms-component.html#_setting_jms_provider_options_on_the_destination) and [here (IBM MQ)](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=applications-creating-destinations-in-jms-application).

> queue://qmgr-name/queue-name?targetClient=1

This prevents JMS classes for MQ from creating a specific message header which may confuse the MQ Java API application.